Is observation the only way to indicate that God is real?
I'm having trouble thinking of any evidence that would make it reasonable to believe in god and I can't wrap my head around it. I can definitely think of examples that would make it seem super obvious that He exists, but the more I think about it, I am starting to see flaws in that too, and I'm wondering whether this is appropriate or delusional.
For example, suppose the words "God is real" was literally written on every DNA strand throughout life. This seems to certainly make it reasonable to believe in God, and it would seem outright delusional to deny Him after this. But presumably, this would seem obvious because it seems absurdly improbable for nature, through some non-design mechanism, to create a reality where "God is real" is written everywhere on DNA strands.
But wouldn't the same line of reasoning apply to God Himself? God would presumably exist without further reason. And what is more "meaningful" or absurdly improbable than a Being who's All Powerful, All Knowing, etc? Why would He require any less of an explanation than "God is real" being written everywhere on DNA strands? And so then my mind thinks: If He can exist without explanation, surely something like DNA strands spelling out "God is real" can perhaps exist without explanation too.
So what then would qualify as reason to believe in god? When it comes to other agents (like humans), we can directly observe them. Would we have to observe God to believe in Him?

Maybe we just don't know how to read the obvious signs?  4000 years ago we wouldn't have been able to read any writing. Carl Sagan proposed that there might be a picture hidden in the numerical expansion of PI or something. Keep looking! You can never say it doesn't exist just because you haven't found it.

Yes, @Scott Rowe, that is true. But Bertrand Russell would point out that a mere failure to find a china teapot revolving about the Sun in an elliptical orbit never proves that it doesn’t exist either. But at what point can we say we’ve searched for the teapot long and carefully enough? There are uncountably many things we have never found. Shall we keep looking for every one of them too? In sum, your comment doesn’t address OP’s question, “What would qualify as reason to believe in god?” It is rather an admonition to endeavor indefinitely to find such a reason.

If you go to a Catholic or Orthodox church, they'll let you look at God's direct physical manifestation in body, blood, soul and divinity. Or at least what they believe to be so. (In fact, if you pretend to be one of the faithful, they'll let you eat him. Don't do that part, it's blasphemy.) I doubt that would convince you that you did anything other than look at a cracker, so I think that you need to re-examine your premises.

@ScottRowe "You can never say it doesn't exist just because you haven't found it." == But you can never believe it until you do.

@PaulTanenbaum yes, that was the point: how long does one feel they should keep searching? Be Albert Michaelson? Or Albert Einstein?

@ScottRowe, why search at all? Why test this particular hypothesis (of the existence of a god) when there are so many, many, many other possible hypotheses that we don’t give a moment’s thought to? I take that to be, in large measure, Russell’s point about his china teapot. We don’t know, for instance, that there isn’t a herd of invisible 32-foot-tall giraffes dancing on the roof of Madison Square Garden. Shall we begin and then “keep” looking?

Logically, there's no argument against searching fruitlessly forever. Something beyond logic has to decide. Well, time for breakfast.

To go even further, some atheists openly and proudly declare that they will refuse to believe that God is real even if such direct observation was readily available. And even if all predictions as described for example in the Book of Revelations were to happen literally exactly as written. They claim they will find some explanation which they will find more plausible than God existing.

@PaulTanenbaum  The possible existence of God has a much more significant effect on our lives than the possible existence of "a herd of invisible 32-foot-tall giraffes dancing on the roof of Madison Square Garden", therefore it makes much more sense to invest effort into investigating the former than the latter.

@vsz How about  "a herd of invisible 32-foot-tall giraffes dancing on the roof of Madison Square Garden who are planning to torture you indefinitely if you don't manage to detect them during the next couple of decades"? Suddenly the hypothetical becomes much more relevant. You can easily fix these toy examples to make them sound as relevant as the God hypothesis. I still think, though, that there is a symmetry breaker between God and these toy examples in that at least there is significantly more testimonial evidence for God hypotheses than for any arbitrary hypothetical one comes up with.

@vsz For instance, you can find lots of stories about people mystically encountering some god X (e.g., the conversion of Paul referenced by mudskipper's answer), but you don't find any such reports for "herds of invisible 32-foot-tall giraffes dancing on the roof of Madison Square Garden". Perhaps a more fair comparison would be between God and Bigfoot, God and aliens, God and ghosts, or God and conspiracy theories, because there are testimonial accounts supporting them as well (however weak/strong that evidence might be).

@user80226 : That torture example is an extremely shallow strawman, which is sadly brought up again and again as if someone was reinventing the wheel in every discussion, and as strawman arguments generally are, is not really conductive to good-faith discussions. While the Bigfoot argument is at least a much more honest attempt at a comparison, it is still not such an easy "gotcha" moment as it would seem at first glance. Look here for a more in-depth analysis of the Bigfoot argument: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/101110/1122

Things that are really significant in our lives would hopefully be quite obvious to us by now. But, on the other hand there's that... Nevermind.

@vsz "That torture example is an extremely shallow strawman" - How is it so?

@vsz "While the Bigfoot argument is at least a much more honest attempt at a comparison" - What would you say about aliens, ghosts, or conspiracy theories?

@user80226 : why is it a strawman? Because no Christian denomination ever said that God said "I'm planning to torture you indefinitely if you don't manage to detect me". If you twist the teachings of a religion in order to be more easy for you to mock it or to argue against it than against the real deal, that is the very definition of a strawman.

@user80226 : About allegations of alien sightings and ghost sightings? The same. Which you would have realized had you read the linked question and its answer. Most, or maybe all the arguments there apply to ghost and alien sightings just as well as to bigfoot sightings.

@vsz So you would completely dismiss cases like this one, this one, or this one?

So I'd like to address the part of your question dealing with God needing an explanation, similar to a message from God needing one.  So in my view, one way to answer this question is to distinguish between immediate and ultimate explanation.  If we conflate the two, then I think that causes some philosophical problems.  Richard Dawkins in his book The God Delusion makes a very similar argument--i.e., the old question, "Who created God?"  A Christian mathematician and philosopher John Lennox has said something like, "Created gods are a delusion."  Which is a good point--because God, by definition, is eternal, transcending the universe's time, space and matter; and thus not created.
So I'd put it this way.  If we ask, "Is God the best explanation of the very origin of the universe?", I think we have to answer that question first.  If the answer is yes (as I would firmly argue), then we would realize that anyone capable of creating the universe--with its time, space, and matter--must be timeless, spaceless, and immaterial.  In other words, such a Being would of necessity exist in transcendence of our universe, and by extension, outside any frame of reference we have to explain His very existence in natural terms.  It would make no sense to require an explanation of the origin of a craftsman by the tools he produces; we can see evidence that there is a craftsman, and we can know something of his character; but we cannot explain where he came from by his tools.  Likewise, for Dawkins to imply that God could not exist because we cannot give a natural answer to the question, "Who created God?" is missing the point.  If God is truly transcendent of the universe, then it is impossible for the universe to contain an explanation of His very existence.  This is the problem with idolatry--it's man creating false gods from natural materials, which gets it backwards; God created us, as well as the wood, etc.  As Paul argued in Acts 17:29:

For in him [God] we live, and move, and have our being; as certain also of your own poets have said, For we are also his offspring.  Forasmuch then as we are the offspring of God, we ought not to think that the Godhead is like unto gold, or silver, or stone, graven by art and man’s device.


Strictly speaking, the question "Who created God?" is not an argument in itself, but rather a refutation of the argument of the first cause.

So, now the question becomes: How do you distinguish between "false idols" and a "true God"? What is the mark of "being created by humans" versus "not created by humans"? And if "not created by humans", why not "nature"?

@mudskipper I think that's a great followup discussion, since my point is limited to arguing that Dawkins's objection isn't valid against an eternal, transcendent God.  If God is eternal and all powerful and all knowing (which seems to reasonably follow from His creating of the universe), then I think there are attributes that naturally follow.  Here's one very brief way I think we could approach it, though more elaboration would be needed:

I'd say God must be entirely coherent to have survived from eternity past as omnipotent and omniscient, since a house divided against itself falls sooner or later; in the realm of epistemology, this complete coherence correlates to absolute light (I John 1:5); in information, to absolute truth (John 14:6, I John 2:21); in morality, to absolute love, goodness, and justice (I John 4:8); and by extension, to perpetual life itself over death (John 14:6; I John 3:14).  Which is precisely how the Bible describes Jesus Christ.

To answer Dawkins' question of "Who created God?" the way that you do, you have to assume that God exists. That's clearly not a proof that He (or She) actually does exist.

@D.Halsey Well, my argument here isn't meant to be proof that God exists, but only that Dawkins's objection against His existence doesn't work against a transcendent and eternal God.  But I don't think God's existence has to be assumed to point out the flaw in Dawkins's argument, though, since a logical flaw is a flaw in any event.

@PeterRankin How can one say “God, by definition, is eternal, transcending the universe's time,…”? To speak about eternity is only possible when refering to the concept of time that we know. Beyond it is an empty word, just a façon de parler.

@JoWehler I use "eternal" in this sense to mean having no beginning, or, there never having been any condition under which something did not exist.  I'll grant, though, that to speak of what things are like beyond our universe's time is generally well out of our depth!  :)

@PeterRankin I see the smiley in your grant :-)   But also saying “never” means “There is no point in time such that …”. Hence again one is referring to time as we know it from our universe. Time determination outside our spacetime can be a delusive trap.

@JoWehler Interesting point, maybe I need to rethink my terminology or something.  I wonder if time language can be used analogously to some kind of "super time" or metatime?  It does seem  very hard to escape references to it in language about eternity though.  In any case, it seems like that's the main issue with Dawkins's argument...that demanding an explanation, in natural terms, of a transcendent Being, is not reasonable.


The concept of God (singular) and gods (plural) is one of the
concepts where claim and reality diverge the furthest. The claim of
mightfulness and the reality of presence.

Since thousands of years the group of theists and the group of
non-theists did not convince each other by their arguments. Each
generation again developed or repeated the arguments which speak for
and against: Myths, revelation, theology, philosophy, science.

Hence I do not expect that the general discussion will find an end
by argumentation. The arguments are on the table.
Those, who search their personal stance in this
debate, have to go through the arguments from religion, theology,
philosophy and science. They have to make their personal decision about what they find
convincing and what not.



What if the great mystery was that God is in every case entirely personal? Sharply the antithesis of reason, belief, argument, idea...

@ScottRowe Please elaborate a bit on what you mean. Do you formulate a new question or do you present a philosophical argument?

Well, there are philosophical ideas that seem innately personal, like qualia. What if proof is not possible because it is one of those sorts of things? I was suggesting a way of agreeing with you.

@ScottRowe: even if a god was innately personal, it could still be explored, for example, by neurology and cognitive sciences. And explaining why people seem to have a collective experience of god (religions) would remain.

@Taladris sounds like a plan.

@ScottRowe: you need a precise definition before you can study something scientifically. My point was that an innately personal god is not immune to scientific study; but it also has the same "issues" as an "universal god: burden of proof, alternative explanations, etc

@Taladris I thought all you needed was a hypothesis? And the great thing is, no matter what the result, even if you were completely 'wrong', you still learn something. It's like throwing darts with a blindfold on and always winning something. How anyone can differ with science defies my comprehension. Let's investigate God already! What do we possibly have to lose?

@ScottRowe: but you can only have a hypothesis if the words that composes it are properly defined. My hypothesis is that "A flumber always wibbs above a grintle, never below". How to test such a hypothesis?

@Taladris a dog can have a hypothesis, come on. Words really have nothing to do with thinking, they just get in the way. Try computer programming: it is mostly intuitions and memories, not logic or math.

@ScottRowe: maybe, words are not the correct... word. I am not sure we can transpose (or to which degree) human cognitive processes (making a hypothesis and testing it) to other animals.  But, when a dog makes a hypothesis like "this stuff I see is delicious food", they have a clear understanding (despite wordless) of the notions they use: delicious=giving a pleasant feeling when eating, etc... Also, no logic or maths in programming? Have you ever opened a book on, for example, algorithmic or data structure?

You ask:

Is observation the only way to indicate that God is real?

No. Fideism (SEP) takes faith as the primary route to knowledge of God. Other's have advocated for divine illumination (SEP). Thus, while observations are one route, the route that provides empirical evidence, religions often tout the virtue of placing "trust" in something or someone, including God himself, herself, or itself depending on your personal preferences or the intuitions and inspirations of the aspirant.


I'm having trouble thinking of any evidence that would make it reasonable to believe in god

Do you need a reason to believe in God? And would hearing a "good reason" give you back the faith of your childhood? Or would it convince you to adopt the faith of some missionary who is trying to convert you?
Personally, I do not believe in any God -- at least, I'm not aware I do. The way "God" is spoken of in (for instance) the Abrahamic religious traditions doesn't mean anything to me. But do I have a reason not to believe? Do I lack faith because I reasoned myself out of my early religious education? Essentially, no. I lack faith because it's impossible for me to give any actual sense or meaning to religious speech. I can see that we have some need for rituals -- at important transition points in life (birth, death, other moments) -- but those need not be religious rituals or at least not rituals that presume any kind of metaphysical doctrine. I can in some cases admire the sacrifices that religious people make for others -- I know they may attribute their altruism to their faith --, but I also see the violence and abuse that seem to be motivated by (or at least justified by) faith. None of this gives me any reason to either believe or not believe. (It gives me reason to say that many religious people are bigots, hypocrites and lack moral sense. But other religious people, no doubt, agree with me.)
So, I'm not an atheist because I have no evidence for a divine presence. It's rather that if I actually did see evidence, I would have to doubt either the stories that are being told or -- my own sanity.
A religious conversion is sometimes decribed in exactly those kind of terms. As a kind of profound, earth-shattering (or rather person-shattering) experience in which someone actually is extremely confused about what is happening to them. The conversion of Paul is a typical example in the Christian tradition (it's not insignificant that he is described as blind for some time immediately after the onset of the experience). William James in The Varieties of Religious Experience describes several similar cases. Does someone who undergoes such an experience afterwards have "reasons" to believe? I don't think so. I think, they have no way to distance themselves from the experience. Reasoning requires some form of distancing, as long as you're overwhelmed, reason cannot assert itself. Whichever way these conversions play out, the "belief" someone expresses afterwards cannot be disentangled from the person they (believe they) are. If this is so, then religious faith (or the lack of faith) can be as immediate and compelling as a supposedly self-evident intuition or as a sensorial observation. But this also implies that any "reasons" may only be secundary rationalizations that can neither fully capture or express the original experience (the religious language game, the religious framing) nor serve as a bridge to justify that experience, make it more certain, or to convince an unbeliever.

"The arrogance of reason has separated us from that love. With the word 'reason', you already feel miles away." - Kabir

The conversion of Paul was indeed very jarring, and a great example--but whether that "jarringness" implies a lack of rationality in his subsequent thought, I would argue, is really a matter of perspective.  I.e., being "knocked senseless," and having sense "knocked into" a person, would both be quite jarring.  :)  People accused Paul of "turning the world upside down," but I heard one preacher say that in reality, the correct perspective is that he was turning the world "right side up."

@PeterRankin - My point was not that after the conversion was suddenly irrational, but rather that the experience itself did not come about by reasoning (even though that may also have contributed) -- just like we cannot by reasoning change what we immediately perceive. My point of view here is very close a Wittgensteinian form of fideism (as mentioned in the fideism link in JD's post).

In other words - in terms of rationality I don't see a major difference between theism and atheism.

Thanks @mudskipper, I'm a little fuzzy on what fideism is, so I'll try to check out that post and link.

The idea that "the same line of reasoning apply to God Himself" is wrong, because you accidentally misunderstood the concept of "God would presumably exist without further reason". That argument is called "the argument from contingency". and it goes like this:

Everything that didn't exist and then someday went into existence, is called a "contingent being", because it's existence is contingent (depends) on something else. For example, a chair is a contingent being, because it's existence is contingent on someone making it.
The thing that caused the contingent being to exist is called a "reason". For example, the reason the chair exists is because someone made it.
If that reason is another contingent being, then that contingent being must also have a reason for its existence.
This line of causes and reasons cannot go on infinitely, therefore there must be a first cause. That is called a "necessary being", because it's impossible for it not to exist, even theoretically.
Since necessary beings are highly unlikely to exist, incomprehensible, even, but must exist, as we have shown, we presume that there is only one of them (There are other arguments for this as well, but I won't go into them here).
People who believe in god call this necessary being god. People who do not believe in god call this necessary being something else (if they ever think about it). But either way, something eternal and uncaused that caused everything else to exist must exist. Your axioms will determine what you call it.

And now you see that your argument that an outstanding miracle could also exist without a reason, is not the same line of reasoning as the argument from contingency. People who believe that god exists without a reason do not believe that anything can exist without a reason, and probably find it quite absurd, even. They just understand that at least one thing must exist without a reason, and they believe that this thing is the god they worship. The "unreasonableness" of god is not the same as the "unreasonableness" of writings on DNA strands, the former means "no cause", the latter means "absurdly improbable".
While this answers your question, I would also like to point out that surprisingly enough, the evidence you made up actually exists: I heard from 4 biologist friends that DNA was undeniably created because it's built like an extremely complicated machine, with many parts that work together to make it function, and in order for life to exist, even the first living being had to have this machine, so it couldn't evolve over generations to become a machine (one of them told me this on his own accord, and I didn't believe him, so I asked the other 3 because I wanted to argue with him). They all said it's well known in the biology community.
Is that sufficient evidence? It depends on your axioms. For example, out of these 4 biologists I mentioned, only 3 believe in god (the other believes in a simulation), out of which only 2 are religious (the other preaches atheism whenever he can, actually), out of which only 1 seems to take religion seriously (He was born and raised as an atheist and became religious because of his biology knowledge, so I guess he changed his axioms).

There is necessarily no way to indicate that God is real, because 'God' as a concept is indefinable by nature. Suppose the fabric of space-time cracked open directly in front of you and a being made of pure love stepped through and claimed to be God. Perhaps it is an alien, or an interdimensional creature, etc. In any case, regardless of their claims or your inability to verify or even comprehend them, you'll always be able to ask the questions: Where did it come from? What existed before it? If it always existed or if "created itself", why/where does the potential for such existence exist? Is it lying? Am I being manipulated?
Ultimately, there can be no rational definition of God (see theological noncognitivism) and any definition you do assign to the word will be necessarily self-contradictory and/or logically insufficient.

God is and will always be a subjective experience, just as my love for Lucy and just as water and just as everything else. The justification of the existence of my love could be justified by external observation (from others) but can always be attributed to a (definitional) illusion of mine too. The reality of water in a glass, is considered objective, but what is this water? Something to satisfy my thirst? A collection of molecules? Part of the nearby river? Quantum fluctuations in the void? > The reality of something is interrelated with the definition of that something (surely something exists here: the water, but what is it?). When you observe something, you observe your definition of it : The World is a game/play in your subjective experience, a construction ie. an illusion. When you realize this, then the only possible reason why (inevitably) the World has consistency is that there must be a reason for this: and this reason if God.

It's like attributing some reason that barns are red. No reason, except that at some point in the past red  happened to be the cheapest color of paint. No metaphysics required, just "In Cash We Trust".

"...the only possible reason why (inevitably) the World has consistency is ...God." seems more like a giant leap of faith than any sort of logical conclusion from your premises.

@D. Halsey, ... equally means .. we can define "God" as the reason (or process, or underlying mechanism) by which the World preserves a (phenomenological and objective-scientific) consistency.

That's fine if you're speaking metaphorically, but unhelpful in a debate about reality.

@D. Halsey, ... but that's exactly my point here : that reality is a metaphor itself, at least in the way we perceive it.

If reality isn't real, then we need to invent some new words for things :-}

Your question seems to dip a bit into a priori vs a posteriori (with the DNA strand argument) - so I'll use that.
A priori knowledge is knowledge you know essentially because someone came up with it. It doesn't truly exist outside of the mind. For example, 1+1=2 is only true because someone said so - you can't prove that it's true outside of using some sort of mathematical axiom (such as "2" is twice as large as "1").
A posteriori knowledge is knowledge you think is true because your experience seems to point to it. People used to assume a posteriori that all swans were white... until people made it to Australia and realised some swans were black. That was improbable, but it turned out to be true. By the same token, you could make the assumption that God is real if you saw "God is real" on DNA, but you couldn't 100% prove it. Even if you see God, and see him prove his existence to you, you wouldn't actually have proven anything - maybe you're going insane (this is probably what you would think if you indeed did see God).
On the other hand, your question asks if it would be possible to indicate the existence of God without seeing him. If "God is real" was written on every DNA strand in existence, that would certainly be indicative of God's existence. But it wouldn't prove it.

The DNA proof is even more problematic.  What language is this message written in, exactly?  You can't write "God is real" using 4 letters (G, C, A and T) and those are arbitrary anyway.  If you assume some sort of encoding, I doubt it would be that hard to find some common series of DNA which you could map to "God is real" in any human language if you can choose the encoding.

If God is real then the message should be visible to everyone. Gravity is real, and no one has a problem recognizing that.

I think the question is based on a false premise and/or ill-formed.  I see two main problems.  The first issue is what is the definition of God that you are using?  There's not one obvious answer to that and if you have a specific idea in mind, what if there is a 'God' but it's not the one you were expecting?  For example, let's assume we a in a simulation running on some high-dimensional being's personal computer and this being is nobody special in their reality.  Yet, they created and can control our universe.  Would such a
being fit your definition of God?
The second, and probably more fundamental issue is the assumption that observation would settle the matter.  You might observe something that in your mind confirms the existence of God, but what is the basis for asserting that a given observation is proof of God?  It comes back to belief.  There is no observation you can have which can't be explained in some other way. Throughout history many unexplained phenomena have been seen as proof of supernatural deities only to be more convincingly explained in other ways.
For example, in ancient times, there was a temple to Zeus/Jupiter.  Hidden high up in the temple was a long metal tube which held a large metal ball in it. The tube could be tilted back and forth to create a sound like thunder.  This was held by many visitors to be proof of the presence of Zeus in his temple and therefore his existence. The 'proof' was based on the incorrect assumption that such a sound inside a temple could only be created by something supernatural.

I think the problem is not that there is no evidence there is a god or God's, it's that any evidence we have is subjective. No we don't have any pictures of a big bearded white guy out in outer space but we have absurd happenings every day that can and have been classified as miracles because of the incredible odds of them happening.
I think Kierkegaard makes a good point when he argued that looking for evidence to base your faith on detracts from what faith is.
If, say, you had absolute knowledge that someone is totally unable to not love you unconditionally, you wouldn't need to have faith in that the people you care about also care about you.
